# How to enable LED Arduino toggle HIGH to LOW on NFC selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arduino, arduino-uno

***Functionality:***

When a user clicks on an image button, the current page (Page A) will navigate to the secondary page (Page B). Hence, when the secondary page is displayed, the 7 LED light that is connected to a relay to the Arduino will light up (toggle from LOW -> HIGH). Hence, the 7 LED will light up with the 7 NFC readers, though the NFC readers are connected separately from the arduino

When the user uses one of the NFC, the program will check if the NFC selected by the user is correct,if it is correct, the LED that is linked to the specific NFC will toggle from HIGH to LOW, LED will be turned off. Else, if the NFC selected by the user is wrong, the LED light will not be turned off.

The LED is connected to arduino. And the javascript is calling the arduino when page A is toggled to page B.

Therefore, the flow is this:

1.) User clicks "Start" Button, page A will navigate to Page B
2.) When Page B is loaded, the 7 LED will Light up.

***What I have done:***

1.) I have created the arduino script that will call the LED relay to light up
2.) Have made use of an ajax _call to call on the arduino script when user clicks on the button to navigate Page A to page B

Code:

***Arduino Code:***
    byte Relay_1 = 0;
    byte Relay_2 = 1;
    byte Relay_3 = 2;
    byte Relay_4 = 3;
    byte Relay_5 = 4;
    byte Relay_6 = 5;
    byte Relay_7 = 6;

```
int time; // Creates  temp 


void setup() {

  // Initialized the Relay pin as an output
  pinMode(Relay_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay_5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay_6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay_7, OUTPUT);

  // Initialized the serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if(Serial.available())
    {
      // read the incoming byte:
      int incomingByte = Serial.read();

      digitalWrite(Relay_1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Relay_2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Relay_3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Relay_4, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Relay_5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Relay_6, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Relay_7, HIGH);
    }
  else{
    int incomingByte = Serial.read();

      digitalWrite(Relay_1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Relay_2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Relay_3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Relay_4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Relay_5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Relay_6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Relay_7, LOW); 
  }
  /*
  while(true)
  {
    // Check if data has been sent from the computer
    if(Serial.available())
    {
      // Assign serial value to temp
      time = Serial.parseInt();

      // Output value to relay
      digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
      delay(time);
      digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
    }
  }
  */

}
```

***The part where HTML calls arduino when user clicks "start" button to enable all LED to light up:***

```js
$("#scentIntroductionPage > .Begin").click(function() {

      //Ajax call to enable LED light to light up
      document.getElementById("scentIntroBeginBtn").style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      $("#gamePage").scentGame();
      $("#scentIntroductionPage").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#gamePage").fadeIn();
        //      $('#stillModal').modal('show');
      })
```

***The part where HTML calls arduino when user selects NFC, if correct: LED will toggle to LOW, else LED will still be HIGH:***

```js
var _chteUID = "042FC58A5949809000";
var _teeUID = "0435C58A5949809000";
var _okUID = "0429C48A5949809000";
var _spsUID = "04A5C88A5949809000";
var _dritsUID = "0430C58A5949809000";
var _vlaUID = "042FC48A5949809000";
var _cusUID = "0488C68A5949809000";

base.selectScent = function(selectedScent) {

  scentIndex++;

  $("#aromaHeader").html("You have picked up a vial.");
  $("#aromaText").html("Please smell the still and guess which ingredient it is.");
  $("." + selectedScent).addClass(scentIndex + "Scent");
  $(".Flavours").removeClass("removeClick");

  $(".Flavours").unbind().click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass(scentIndex + "Scent")) {

      $("#aromaHeader").html("GOOD JOB!<br><br> MATCH THE REMAINING SCENTS.");
      $("#aromaText").html("");
      $(".Flavours").addClass("grayScale")
      $(this).removeClass("grayScale"); // Stay in coloured
      $(this).removeClass("Flavours");
      $(this).addClass("removeClick"); // Remove Clickability
      $(".Flavours").addClass("removeClick");

      previousScentArr.push(selectedScent);

      if ($(".Flavours").length == 0) {
        // All ingredient has been selected
        $("#aromaHeader").html("CONGRATULATIONS<br><br> YOU HAVE MATCHED ALL AROMAS CORRECTLY.");
        $("#aromaText").html("");
        // Go back to home & Reset

        $("#gamePage > .Back").fadeOut();

        setTimeout(function() {

          $(".navigationList > li").removeClass("navBorder_Bottom");
          $("#gamePage").fadeOut(function() {
            $("#Menu").css({
              top: -121
            });
            $("#homePage").fadeIn();
          })
          $("#gamePage").empty();
          base.reset();
        }, 5500);
      } else {
        // Set buffer time
        // There are still more ingredient to choose
        // Ensure that all vials are back into positon
        var ensureAllReadyInterval = setInterval(function() {

          console.log("base:" + base.checkAllInPosition());

          if (base.checkAllInPosition() == "false") {
            $("#aromaHeader").html("Please place the vial back into position.");
          } else if (base.checkAllInPosition() == "true") {
            clearInterval(ensureAllReadyInterval);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#aromaHeader").html("All vials are in position. Please choose a new vial.");
              base.detectFirstScent();
            }, 1500);
          }
        }, 500);
      }

    } else {

      $("#aromaHeader").html("THAT'S NOT THE RIGHT MATCH. <br><br> TRY AGAIN.");
      $("#aromaText").html("");

    }
  })
}

base.init();

}
```

***Issue:***

I have only managed to get the arduino light to toggle from LOW to HIGH state only when user clicks on the button.

However, I am absolutely stuck in accomplishing on the part where :

1. when the user selects the correct NFC, the LED will toggle from LOW->HIGH
2. when user still selects the wrong NFC, the LED will not toggle but still remain in state HIGH.

I need to achieve this in my javascript.

Can I please get some help? Thank you.

I have absolutely have no idea on how to achieve those 2.